# Prerequisites for beginning system programming and kernel level programs

Tags: linux, operating-system

Apart from basic c and c++ coding what all is required to make kernel level programs and modules and where can one begin from in order to start making such modules. 
Can someone please suggest some online resources for learning to write kernel level modules.

Answer (score 2):

I do some degree of kernel programming in my job and my sincere advice would be to narrow the scope when you are learning at the beginning and then expand...

First things first, Kernel programming is very different from system programming:

- Kernel developers focus on interfaces, data structures, algorithms, and optimization for the core of the operating system.
- System programmers write daemons, utilities, and other tools for automating common or difficult tasks.

Some resources that may help you kick start:

Start here:

http://kernelnewbies.org/

Read the FAQ:

http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ

Read the "Where Do I Begin Page"

http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/WhereDoIBegin

Read some books:

http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBooks

Hope this helps....